# AngularJS ng-include values isn't bound

Tags: angularjs

I have a partial where i include another partial like this

```
<div ng-include src="template"></div>
```

In the controller i bind template to the path to the partial i want to include. However, the fields in the sub-partial isn't bound to the values in the scope. For example, i have an input field like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title"/>
```

No value is presented in the textbox. If i set `value="{{ title }}"` instead, the value `{{ title }}` is rendered. So no value is bound. I've set `$scope.title = "test" in my controller`

Comment: where is the controller specified? On the parent one or on the child one?

Comment: The controller is specified in the parent of the ng-include element

Comment: The situation which you say you are in can be, but you have to make some slight fiddling to achieve it. What happens if you put the controller on the child? (Edit: I know the scope should be inherited, but am just curious) Maybe an ng-include severes the scope inheritance?

Comment: I tried declaring the controller in the child partial instead, but with the same result.

Comment: what if inside in the partial you just put {{title}}? Should be there. Can you paste the code for parent, controller and the partial. You got my curiosity.

Comment: Oh my, that works. I suppose something must have been wrong in my sub-partial, with the HTML or the Angular syntax (i was actually converting from Mustache templating syntax to Angular and something might have been wrong)

Comment: Nice, glad it worked. I was going to even do some fiddle to check, cause i was starting to suspect a bug in angular itself.